# Directory layout and `got get ...` for Go language

Tags: go, module, directory-structure

Suppose I have `main.go` in directory `project/` and have subdirectory `project/pkg/mydb/` that is used by `main.go`.

To add a dependency to my code inside `mydb/` I should run `go get ...` in that subdir `mydb/` or in top-level project directory (`project/`)?

Also where `main.go` should reside: directly in `project/` or in `project/src/`?

Comment: Please read https://go.dev/doc/, especially the Tutorials which explain exactly this. Use modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go only think in term of module and packages. Usually your module would be `project/` and can be composed of one or several packages (`project/pkg/mydb` can be one of them)

Only go modules have dependencies. So you should run `go get` in `project`

`main.go` can be wherever you want, it will just change whether you need to run `go build .` or `go build ./src`

(This is only applicable if you use go modules, so if you have a go.mod in your `project`. But if you should be using them anyway)